# sscanf is not working as intended

Tags: c, printf, scanf

So I'm writing a program for my class and I have a line read in from a text file as follows:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
```

That gets from a text file and I've been using line[index] matching a character to get specific lines from that text file.

The text file line looks as follows;

```
dbr:Edmonton    rdf:type    yago:WikicatTownsInAlberta ,
```

I've been using sscanf to get specific data from each line.

```
sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s",triple[t][0],triple[t][1],triple[t][2],triple[t][3]);
```

Now what I expected to get from this was:

```
triple[t][0] == dbr:Edmonton 
triple[t][1] == rdf:type 
triple[t][2] == yago:WikicatTownsInAlberta 
triple[t][3] == ,
```

Instead what my output was:

```
Object:dbr:rdf:yago, 
Predicate:rdf:yago, 
Subject:yago,
Extraneous: ,
```

Yet, when I printf(%s,line) I get the line exactly as represented in the file.

This could be totally stupid, but I really hope you can help me.

Cheers,

The entirety of the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

sqlite3 * db;       // THE DATABASE
sqlite3_stmt * stmt;    // THE SQL STATEMENT

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Do Argument Stuff, Open Database

int rc;
char * class;
char * data;

if (argc!=3)
{
    printf("Usage: <programfile.c database data>\n");
    printf("You specified %d arguments. You need to specify 3.\n",argc);
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Correct Number of Inputs!\n");
    //printf("Argument %d: %s",argc,argv[0]);
    //printf("Argument %d: %s",argc,argv[1]);
    //printf("Argument %d: %s",argc,argv[2]);

    data = argv[2];
    printf("Data: %s\n",data);
    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
}

// Open File

FILE * file = fopen(data,"r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR: File open error.\n");
    return 1;
}

/* Read the file */
char line[256];
char prefix[256][200];
char prefixURI[256][200];
char triple[256][200][4];
// object, predicate, subject

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
    //printf("%s\n",line);
    int p = 0, t=0;
    // Handle COMMENTS and Blank Lines
    if (line[0] == '#' || line[0] == '\n')
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Handle "@prefix"
    else if (line[0] == '@')
    {
        // Load prefix (rdf: into prefix) and the URI into prefixURI.
        sscanf(line,"@prefix %s %s",prefix[p],prefixURI[p]);
        printf("Prefix Encoded: %s URI: %s\n",prefix[p],prefixURI[p]);
        p++;
    }
    // handle data triples
    else if (line[3] == ':')
    {
        printf("%s",line);
        sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s",triple[t][0],triple[t][1],triple[t] [2],triple[t][3]);
        printf("Object:%s \nPredicate:%s \nSubject:%s\nExtraneous: %s\n",triple[t][0],triple[t][1],triple[t][2],triple[t][3]);
    }








} // end getWhile Loop


fclose(file);
```

}

Comment: How is `triple` defined? Always show the *full* code in question, not just some lines of it.

Comment: It's difficult to debug incomplete code. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I've added the full code

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: Also; a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example does *not* mean your entire source file.

Comment: Do you expect `"dbr:Edmonton"` to fit in a 4 character `triple[t][0]`?

Comment: what is the contents of the non-standard header file: `sqlite3.h`?

Comment: the posted code uses nothing from the `math.h` header file,  It is a bad idea to include header files that are not being used.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: this line is not correct:  `if (argc!=3)` the `argc` parameter includes the first argument of `argv[]` which is the executable name.  Suggest:  `if (argc!=4)`

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, ....)`  rather than `printf( ... )`

Comment: following this line: `rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);`  The value in `rc` needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the failure of the call to `fopen()` should be followed by closing the database file, before exiting the program

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 4, 200, 256.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout  the code.

Comment: the posted code seems to be assuming that only text characters are in the data base.  Such an assumption is usually not true.  Suggest using `sqlite3_exec*(` rather than `fgets()` to read the record/fields in the data base.  This will also result in most of the code after the call to `sqlite3_exec()` being replaced.

Comment: the proper way to close a `sqllite3` data base is calling:  `sqlite3_close()` not `fclose()`

Comment: the posted code fails to setup the `sqlite3_stmt * stmt;` query statement for reading the data base and fails to make use of that query statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If str is a character array with more than one row, sscanf reads the characters in column order. you have to replace you else if(line[3]==':') condition

the correct way is :

```
  // handle data triples
    else if (line[3] == ':')
    {
        printf("%s",line);
        sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s",triple[0][t],triple[1][t],triple[2] [t],triple[3][t]);
        printf("Object:%s \nPredicate:%s \nSubject:%s\nExtraneous: %s\n",triple[0][t],triple[1][t],triple[2][t],triple[3][t]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank yooouu so much.

Comment: I did not do the down vote.  However, the problem with this answer is that the OPs posted code is not correctly accessing a data base. So this answer would be acceptable for a regular file, but not a data base file.